# How to create a Windows service that monitors the version of a specific application and modifies a file if it changes

Tags: c#, windows, service

I have very little experience with C#. I'm in the process of learning it, but am finding writing the code for this to be a bit above my skill level.

Here is the scenario: at the company I work at, we have about 1200 devices with the same program on them, written by a third party. We've had to make some modifications to one of their config files to allow the application to work correctly in our environment.

Here is the majority of the config file:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<configuration>
    <appSettings file="%ProgramData%\NCR\RAL\AlhAdmin.exe.config">
        <add key="ConfigurationDataFile" value="AlhAdmin.xml"/>     <!--Config Data Xml File -->
        <!--Log File Details -->
        <!--<add key="ApplicationLogPath" value=""/>-->
        <add key="ApplicationLogName" value="AlhAdmin"/>
        <!--Number of Days to keep log -->
        <add key="ApplicationLogDaysToRetain" value="2"/>
        <!--Port Number to be entered here-->
        <add key="SocketListenPort" value="11000"/>
        <add key="MulticastUDPSendPort" value="11001"/>
        <add key="MulticastUDPSendBroadcastAddress" value="224.168.100.25"/>
        <add key="MulticastUDPListenPort" value="11002"/>
        <add key="MulticastUDPListenBroadcastAddress" value="224.168.100.35"/>
        <add key="DefaultSelTime" value="30"/>
        <add key="DefaultTermSelTime" value="30"/>
        <add key="DefaultLANWaitTime" value="2"/>
        <!--DisplayMessage Form-->
        <add key="MessageDisplayFile" value="DisplayMessages.xml"/>
        <!--RFC: 55071-->
        <add key="UltraVNCFolderPathInFS" value="\ExtData\RAL\UltraVNC"/>
        <add key="StartUpFolderPath" value="C:\Documents and Settings\All Users\Start Menu\Programs\Startup"/>
        <add key="ProgramFileFolderPath" value="C:\Program Files"/>
        <add key="NetworkGroupBMP" value="Network.ico"/>
        <!--RFC: 52790-->
        <add key="DebugLevel" value="25"/>
        <add key="BaseIPToIncr" value="192.168.0"/>
        <add key="BaseIPToIncrSubNet" value="255.255.255.0"/>
        <add key="CheckForConnectedNIC" value="0"/>         <!-- Check for only NICs that are connected /-->
        <add key="AddAdminGroup" value="0"/>
        <add key="SetGatewayInfo" value="1" />    <!-- Wheter order to set the server gateway and DNS entries on the terminal-->
        <add key="CopyRemotely" value="1"/>             <!-- Whether to copy remotely or use Bootdrv share /-->
        <!-- add key="RemoteCopyPort" value="11003" /-->        <!-- Remote copy port on which server is copying /-->
        <!-- add key="ServerIPEntryRequired" value="1" --/>     <!-- Pops the screen to select Server Name/IP /-->
        <!-- add key="QWERTY" value="0" /-->                    <!-- Keyboard style for above screen /-->
        <!-- add key="IPScreenTimeout" value="120" /-->         <!-- Timeout for Server IP Screen /-->
        <!-- add key="Base1stOctet" value="1" /-->              <!-- Start number for the 1st Octet /-->
        <!-- add key="Default1stOctet" value="1" /-->           <!-- Default 1st Octet for IP Screen /-->
        <!-- add key="Default2ndOctet" value="0" /-->           <!-- Default 2nd Octet for IP Screen /-->
        <!-- add key="Default3rdOctet" value="0" /-->           <!-- Default 3rd Octet for IP Screen /-->
        <!-- add key="Default4thOctet" value="1" /-->           <!-- Default 4th Octet for IP Screen /-->
        <!-- add key="DefaultServerName" value="" /-->          <!-- Default Server Name for IP Screen /-->
        <!-- add key="SetEncryptedPassword" value="1" /-->      <!-- Sets password encrypted /-->
        <add key="SetDefaultDomain" value="0" />    <!-- Sets Default domain in the registry /-->
        <!-- add key="BackupData" value="0" /-->    <!-- Backs up  Data folder over to ExtData\RAL\Data /-->
        <!-- add key="DisableAdmin" value="0" /-->    <!-- disables administrator account  /-->
    </appSettings>
    <startup>

    <supportedRuntime version="v4.0" sku=".NETFramework,Version=v4.0,Profile=Client"/></startup>
    <runtime>
        <generatePublisherEvidence enabled="false"/>
    </runtime>
</configuration>
```

We've had to uncomment the line `<!-- add key="ServerIPEntryRequired" value="1" --/>`. It is already done on our image, so it's not something that we have to change usually. But, in testing new versions of the software, I've found that when I install a new version, the current version is completely uninstalled, and then the new version is installed, meaning the modified config file is reset to it's default state.

What I am trying to do is create a Windows service that monitors this application, and if the version of the application changes, then to modify the config file. I found a method to get the version of an application, which I think will work:

```
private string GetSoftwareVersion (string softwareName)
        {
            string stringVersion = string.Empty;
            try
            {
                var version = (object)null;
                // Query the system registry for the version of the given software
                var searcher = new ManagementObjectSearcher(
                    "SELECT * FROM Win32_Product where Name LIKE " +
                    "'%" + softwareName + "%'");
                foreach (ManagementObject obj in searcher.Get())
                {
                    version = obj["Version"];
                }
                if (version != null)
                {
                    stringVersion = (String)version;
                }
                // If the given product is not found in the list of installed products in control panel
                else
                {
                    stringVersion = "The given application is not found in the list of Installed Programs.";
                }
            }
            // Exception handling
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                stringVersion = "An error occured while getting Version" +
                    " (" + e.Message + ")";
            }
            return stringVersion;
        }
```

What I'm more unsure about is modifying the config file, as it is not a true XML file as it does not have a namespace. After that, it's figuring out how to actually monitor the application.

Hopefully this is enough information to get started. Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.filesystemwatcher(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: @KenWhite:Thanks. That does help a little. I've figured out how to modify the config file. I'm still not sure how I would use that with the FileSystemWatcher though. Mainly because from what I've seen, FileSystemWatcher happens almost immediately. Because the entire folder is going to be removed, and then re-populated, I would need to modify the file after it is re-populated. Is this possible?

Comment: If you're watching the directory, and you get several deletion notifications (the folder being removed) and then several creation notifications right after, that might be enough to tell you that the folder had been repopulated, at which point you can update the config file. Alternately, you could just watch the configuration file itself to see when it's deleted and re-created.

Answer (score 0):

The filesystemwatcher idea is a great idea but deteriorates if there are many folders being watched.  As any idea been given to running the check periodically?  Installed as a service, you can schedule it to run every hour (or whatever) and look for changes.

Is this configured as a agent that runs on the remote machines to report its findings back to a server?